# Saving data from html table in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a view as

```
  <div class="main_content">
    <div class="form_container">
        <h1>
            Save Build Document Revision</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <%=Html.Hidden("TotalRows", Model.ToList().Count)%>
                <table id="ListBuild" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="instruction_grid">
                    <tr>
                        <th align="left" class="link_sl_no">
                            Build document
                        </th>
                        <th align="left" class="link_title">
                            Revision
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <% foreach (var item in Model)
                       { %>
                    <tr id="<%= Html.Encode(item.BldDocId) %>" style="width: auto">
                        <td>
                            <label id="BldDoc<%= Html.Encode(item.BldDocId) %>" class="BldDoc">
                                <%= Html.Encode(item.BldDocTitle) %></label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="Rev<%= Html.Encode(item.BldDocId) %>" name="Revision" class="BldDocRev"
                                style="width: auto;">
                                <% for (int i = 1; i <= item.BldDocMaxRevision; i++)
                                   { %>
                                <option value="' <%=i %> '">
                                    <%=i %></option>
                                <%} %>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <% } %>
                </table>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="button_panel">
                    <input name="button" type="submit" class="btn_create_doc flotted" id="SaveBldDocRev"
                        value="Save" />
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <%--</div>
    </div>--%>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
</div>
```

When save is click i need to save values in the table to database. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Maybe you are missing the form tag is the first thing. You already have the total rows in your hidden input. I think you almost made it. Just put on some modifications in your code.

1. You should name your label and select with sequentially number. such as from 1 to total rows. for example:
   " class="BldDoc"><%=Html.Encode(item.BldDocTitle) %>
   where i is the increment number.
2. You should also put the item.BldDocId in the hidden input.
3. When you receive the FormCollection on post action in the controller, you can simply insert the data into your database recursively.

## If you don't understand what I just said. Let me know!!

Below is the view page.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="TotalRows" value="<%=Model.ToList().Count%>" />
    <table>
        <% int i=1; %>
        <% foreach(var item in Model) { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label name="label_<%=i%>"><%=item.value1%></label>
                <select name="select_<%=i%>">
                    <% foreach(var s in selectvalue) { %>
                    <option value="<%=s.value%>">
                        <%=s.text%>
                    </option>
                    <% } %>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% i++; %>
        <% } %>
    </table>
</form>
```

And your controller should be something like that:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(FormCollection collection)
{
     int totalRows = Convert.ToInt32(collection["TotalRows"]);
     for (int i = 1; i <= totalRows; i++)
     {
          string labelValue = collection["label_" + i];
          string selectValue = collection["select_" + i];

          //your insert method here
     }

     return View();
}
```

I give the example above. if you can't understand, just let me know...

Comment: I have included only the main part of my view. I didn't understand the incremental value to label name. Aldo how can i access the selected value of the dropdownlists. I am trying to use Jquery for this. Will this will help?